# Get all list items in provided-hosted add-in (SharePoint Online)

Tags: provider-hosted-app, list-item, splistitemcollection

I am trying to get all items of a list and show the Title.

Although i can get a list and show its Title i cannot get its items. It seems i use the suggested code but the `ListItemCollection` object has no items in it.

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {             
                CamlQuery caml = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
                ListItemCollection collListItems = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Issues Test List").GetItems(caml);                
                clientContext.Load(collListItems);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (ListItem item in collListItems)
                {
                    ViewBag.Item0 = item["Title"];
                }
            }

                return View();
        }
```

Comment: Which errors are you facing while accessing other column values from `collListItems` object?

Comment: i dont get an error, but collListItems is empty. so it does not enter in foreach code. But when i execute code for the list title and itemCount i get the list name and count of items correctly. so the list is not empty and i can see items from sharepoint and by executing similar code from PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

found the solutions here:
http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Displaying-SharePoint-list-items-in-MVC-web-grid-of-a-Provider-Hosted-App

i had to assign Permissions to Web for full control.